# ¿Cómo podría invertir el orden de este vector?

Tags: c++, array, vectores

Tengo el siguiente código en C++ y quisiera invertir el orden (de mayor a menor) en el qu imprime los números impares.

```
int x,cont,z,i,tabla[50];

i=0;
for(x=0; x<=50; x++) {
    
    cont=0;
    if (x%2==1) {
        tabla[i]=x;
        i++;
    }
}
for (x=0;x<i;x++){
    printf("%d\n",tabla[x]);
}

return 0;}
```

Comment: Una posible solución es iniciar x en 50 y decrementar hasta llegar a 0: `for(x = 50; x >= 0; x--)`. O lo mismo pero con el segundo for: `for(x = i - 1; x >= 0; x--)`. Por cierto, podrías mejor iniciar `x = 1` e incrementar `x += 2` en el primer ciclo: `for(x = 1; x <= 50; x += 2)`?

Answer (score 1):

Dado que, una sucesión de números impares se genera a partir de un valor inicial (generalmente parte en uno) cuyo siguiente valor se obtiene incrementando en dos unidades al valor inicial, se crea la siguiente clase que encapsula ese comportamiento.

```
class Impar{
    int contador;
public:
    Impar() : contador{ 1 }{}

    int generar(){
        int temp{ contador };
        contador += 2;
        return temp;
    }
};
```

El método constructor inicializa en uno el atributo `contador`, mientras que el método `generar` genera el número impar siguiente al valor inicial, de manera que, con cada llamada que hagamos al método `generar` estaremos generando nuestra sucesión de números impares. Ejemplo de uso:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    const int MAX{ 50 };
    int array[MAX];

    // instanciamos un objeto de la clase Impar
    Impar impar;

    // llenamos el array con los numeros que genera nuestra clase
    for(int i{}; i < MAX; i++){
        array[i] = impar.generar();
    }
   
    // mostrar numeros
    for(int i{}; i < MAX; i++){
        std::cout<<array[i]<<" ";
    }

    std::cout<<"\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Ahora, para tener el array con los elementos ordenados de mayor a menor (descendente) tienes que usar la función `std::sort` de la biblioteca `<algorithm>` y tendrás que crear una función que implemente la lógica del ordenamiento descendente que necesita tu array, de la siguiente forma:

```
// aqui nuestra funcion con la logica de ordenamiento descendente
bool ordenDescendente(int a, int b){
    return (a > b);
}
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // para funcion sort

int main(){
    const int MAX{ 50 };
    int array[MAX];
    Impar impar;

    for(int i{}; i < MAX; i++){
        array[i] = impar.generar();
    }

    // descripcion de argumentos de izquierda a derecha de sort
    // 1°: inicio del array
    // 2°: final del array
    // 3°: funcion de ordenamiento descendente
    std::sort(array,array + MAX,ordenDescendente);

    // mostrar array con los elementos ordenados
    for(int i{}; i < MAX; i++){
        std::cout<<array[i]<<" ";
    }

    std::cout<<"\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```